# I want to migrate blockly to newer version by use migrate script but it didn't work

Tags: javascript, migrate, blockly

I tried to migrate my blockly code from version 8.x.x to 10.x.x so i used @blockly/migrate plugin script but nothing in my code are changed.

Command that i used was `npx @blockly/migrate rename -i --from 8 --to 10 ./pathofmyfiles`. Log showed message `Migrate renaming in myfile`.